# Fetch multi level data from API using Laravel

Tags: php, json, laravel, api

I'm trying to get data from the API, but I can't figure it out how to make it possible to return it in... In simple words it would be like this:
Data1 has Data2 inside it. So I'm fetching data from Data1 but I can't get deeper.

Controller:

```
    <?php
        
        namespace App\Http\Controllers;
        
        use Illuminate\Http\Request;
        use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;
        
        class InvList extends Controller
        {
            //
            function list()
            {
               $data = Http::get('http://192.168.50.253:1880/invlist')->json();
        
                return view('invlist', ['data'=>$data]);
            }
        }
    
  ?>
```

View:

```
    <ul>
        @foreach ($data as $item)
            <li> <a href="#">{{$item['Name']}}</a></li>
        @endforeach
    </ul>
```

Routes:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Route::get('invlist', "InvList@list");

Route::get('');
?>
```

I'm getting json from the API(http://192.168.50.253:1880/invlist):

```
{
        "Id": 4177,
        "Name": "Import",
        "StatusID": 1
    }
```

Till this point I'm good. But now I want to get Data2 witch is under the ID:4177 -> http://192.168.50.253:1880/invlist/4177

```
{
        "Id": 1,
        "Name": "ImportData",
        "rowNum": 2,
        "Barcode": 123456789
    }
```

Sequence:

1. Get data1 display it on the view.
2. Press on one of the name from Data1.
3. Get Data2 witch is inside of Data1. Display it in the view.
4. Update the data2.

Comment: You are asking a lot here as this would require creating more controllers, adding JS to make the page interactive, so explain how ajax requests work, etc... Too much to explain for me at least. But tip: Look into laravel livewire.

Comment: I will. Thank you.